# Count specific columns based on multiple criteria and ranges of different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, countif, google-sheets-query

I'm working with the following table:

[image: Table Screenshot]

I need a formula I can use on a different sheet that counts how many classes were cancelled for each of the groups like:

```
GE COL INT MIX W     2
GE COL INT 1 W       0
```

The criteria to decide if a class was cancelled or not is to type "C" in one of the columns for the class (i.e. January 2, meaning second class in January). In the example table you can see that the 4 people are part of 2 groups, 2 per group; if I write C for 2 of them in the same group I want the macro to only count 1 cancelled class instead of counting both "C"s.

All of the space where the "C"s will be written (Month columns) is a named range = "Attendance" and there's also a named range for the names of all groups = "Groups".

I'm using the following simple formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(METRICS!F:F,H5,Attendance,"C")
```

`METRICS!F:F` Refers to the sheet where the table I just showed you is and `F` is the column where the levels are. `H5` is the cell in the other sheet where I'm comparing the group name to make sure it's the same. `Attendance` is the range where I'll be writing "C".

However, I get the error:

> Array arguments to `COUNTIFS` are of different size.

And that would count all "C"s, not only the ones I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add a column after the group name that counts absences, and then use `UNIQUE()` over the group names and absence count to get a unique list. eg.

[image]

Alternately, to do this without the extra column, first create a unique list of group names with `=UNIQUE(Groups)`.

Then add a named range called `GroupAttendance` that includes the ranges of both `Groups` and `Attendance`.

Lastly, fill the column next to the group names with:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(UNIQUE(GroupAttendance), UNIQUE(Groups) = A2), "C")
```

eg.

[image]

Comment: Well this is actually giving a result of 0 and not an error, but no matter how many "C"s I add the result is still 0.

Comment: Hrm. I'll just rough up your data and see what I did wrong. :)

Comment: Aha. `Attendance` is not just a single column. Silly me. When you have duplicate groups, do they also have duplicate cancellation info?

Comment: Yeah, attendance is indeed the whole area where attendance is taken (January 1, 2, 3, etc, all those columns). Indeed, all students who are part of that group would get a mark for the cancelled class. In the table example Alexander and Andres Felipe are both in the group GE COL INT MIX W. If the first class in January was cancelled, both of them would receive a "C" in the same Column, but the formula should count 1 cancellation, since I did not cancel 2 classes, I cancelled 1 class with 2 students in it. Thanks!